# How to achieve Dungeon Mayhem-esque iconography with Squib?

Tags: ruby, squib

I've been reading through the Squib docs and messing with my own example but haven't yet found a syntax for having an arbitrary number of symbols the way that Dungeon Mayhem has in the upper left of its cards.

I want to be able to specify that a card can have multiples of each icon and have them "stack" on the left side of the card.

For now, I'm assuming the icons are always in a specific order (all specials, all defends, all attacks, all draws, all heals, all plays) but it might be nice to eventually supply the order as well (in which case I'd probably use some string like "daah" for Defend, Attack, Attack, Heal)

Some examples:

- 4 attacks
- 3 defense
- 2 draws
- 2 extra plays
- 2 draws, 1 heal
- 1 special power
- 1 special power, 1 heal
- 1 special power, 1 extra play

Here are the cards that show these examples:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! You can do this a couple of different ways. Here's one way from this sample: https://github.com/andymeneely/squib/blob/dev/samples/ranges/_ranges.rb#L52-L60.

```
  # Useful idiom: draw a different number of images for different cards
  # hearts = [nil, 1, 2] # i.e. card 0 has no hearts, card 2 has 2 hearts drawn
  1.upto(2).each do |n|
    range = hearts.each_index.select { |i| hearts[i] == n}
    n.times do |i|
      svg file: 'glass-heart.svg', range: range,
          x: 150, y: 55 + i * 42, width: 40, height: 40
    end
  end
```